# Xamarin Forms Showing animated label at startup

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created a ContentPage with a string: `public MainPage(string Status)`.
Now when I call this page with the value "Mail sent" I want to slide in a label from the top for 2 seconds and slide it back up again. Now the label is in a `RelativeLayout` like this:

```
<Label x:Name="txtMailSent" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Green" Text="A verification mail has been sent."
    RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=0}"
    RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=0}"
    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0.025,Constant=0}"/>
```

So I created this code:

```
public MainPage(string Status)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SizeChanged += (s, a) =>
    {
        txtMailSent.TranslateTo(0, -txtMailSent.Height, 1, Easing.Linear);
    };

    if (Status == "Mail sent")
    {
        new Action(async () => await ShowMail())();
    }
}

private async Task ShowMail()
{
    await txtMailSent.TranslateTo(0, 0, 400, Easing.Linear);
}
```

But when I startup the app and give that parameter, no label shows up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As suggested below, you should probably look at triggering the animation in OnAppearing, but I think the primary issue with your code above is that you create an Action that points to ShowMail, but you don't invoke it. Just creating the action isn't enough. You could just call the ShowMail function directly, so I'm not sure why you didn't do that, but you may still have the issue that it starts executing before the page is actually visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say your code executes before visual elements are fully rendered. You can do something like this.

```
private string status = string.Empty;
public MainPage(string Status)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    status = Status;

    SizeChanged += (s, a) =>
    {
        txtMailSent.TranslateTo(0, -txtMailSent.Height, 1, Easing.Linear);
    };
}

protected async  override void OnAppearing()
{
    if (status == "Mail sent")
    {
        await txtMailSent.TranslateTo(0, 0, 4000, Easing.Linear);
        await Task.Delay(200);
        await txtMailSent.TranslateTo(0, -txtMailSent.Height, 4000, Easing.Linear);
    }
}
```